# Sharepoint 2013: Document Library Template

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

Currently, I am creating document library in Sharepoint 2013. However I don't want default document library outlook. Can I change the outlook for document library as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create new custom view.aspx form in sharepoint designer and change look and feel.